# How to make vertical lines with connecting dots?

Tags: css

How can I make the below horizontal lines to vertical lines like below image

[image]

Below is the code for vertical lines with connecting dots which I have tried:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

.progress {

  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  top:16px;
  vertical-align:top
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order</span>

  </div> <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>

  </div> <span class="bar active"></span>

  <div class="circle active"> <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Are you simply looking to rotate the orientation of the working snippet to be vertical?  Or do you need to match other aspects of the screenshot (gaps between the circles and lines, radio-like treatment, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block`

```
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: block;
}
```

And interchanged `width` and `height` of progress bar

```
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 6px; // already given 80px in question
  height: 80px; // already given 6px in question
}
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

.progress {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 0px 0px 16px;
  border-radius: 0;
  top:0;
  vertical-align:top;
  left:0;
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100vw - 130px);
  margin-top: -25px;
  text-align:left;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">When the text characters are more the alignment changes and not overlaps with circle and bar </span>

  </div> <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>

  </div> <span class="bar active"></span>

  <div class="circle active"> <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: I have noticed a issue here. When the text characters are more the alignment changes and overlaps with circle and bar

Answer (score 2):

Was it necessary? In css, I marked my changes.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

/*add*/
.label_box {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
/*--------------*/

.progress {

  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  
  display: flex; /*add*/
  flex-direction: column; /*add*/
  align-items: center; /*add*/
  justify-content: space-between; /*add*/
  height: 355px;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.progress .bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  /*margin: 0 -5px 17px -5px;*/ /*remove*/
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  /*top:16px;*/ /*remove*/
  vertical-align:top; /*add*/
  
  transform: rotate(90deg); /*add*/
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px; /*add*/
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  /*margin-left: -30px;*/ /*remove*/
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  /*margin-top: 5px;*/ /*remove*/
  
   margin-left: 10px; /*add*/
   text-align: start; /*add*/
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done">
   <div class="label_box"> 
    <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order</span>
   </div>

  </div> <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done"> 
   <div class="label_box"> 
    <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>
   </div>

  </div> <span class="bar active"></span>

  <div class="circle active">
   <div class="label_box"> 
    <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>
   </div>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
/* Form Progress */

body{
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 }
.progress {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.progress .circle{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 }
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.progress .bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 -5px 17px -20px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  top:16px;
  vertical-align:top
}
.progress .circle .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
  color: #b5b5ba;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -80px;
}
/* Done / Active */

.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
  background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #8bc435;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
  color: #444;
}
.progress .circle.active .label {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #0c95be;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.progress .circle.active .title {
  color: #0c95be;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">1</span>
    <span class="title">Order</span>

  </div> <span class="bar done"></span>

  <div class="circle done"> <span class="label">2</span>
    <span class="title">Address</span>

  </div> <span class="bar active"></span>

  <div class="circle active"> <span class="label">3</span>
    <span class="title">Payment</span>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: text is overlapping with bars

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudo class to make the stick and use position to center it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .dots::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 2rem;
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
    </style>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="flex items-center my-3">
        <span class="dots relative w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
        <p class="ml-2">Hello world</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center my-3">
        <span class="dots relative w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
        <p class="ml-2">Hello world</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center my-3">
        <span class="dots relative w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
        <p class="ml-2">Hello world</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center my-3">
        <span class="dots relative w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
        <p class="ml-2">Hello world</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center my-3">
        <span class="dots relative w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
        <p class="ml-2">Hello world</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center my-3">
        <span class="dots relative w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-gray-500"></span>
        <p class="ml-2">Hello world</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```